# How to use an OR condition with the content of a snort rule

Tags: snort, ftp

I understand that if you specify multiple contents then the rule triggers only if ALL the content conditions are satisfied.

But I want to create a rule that will trigger even if any one of the content keywords are detected. Note that it has to be in a single rule. Perhaps something like this:

`alert tcp any any -> any 21 (msg: "FTP traffic"; content: "USER" OR content: "PASS"; sid: 666;)`

What I am trying to achieve is a rule that block only FTP traffic on port 21 but allows other traffic. So I figured I could just list all FTP raw commands in the content. Note that it has to be a SINGLE rule.

Thank you

Comment: pcre is your friend

Answer (score 2):

This concept will do the trick for you.

```
alert tcp any any -> any 21 (msg:"FTP traffic"; pcre:"/USER|PASS/i"; sid:666; rev:1;)
```

This is a case-insensitive (`/i`) Perl Compatible Regular Expression (`pcre`) match for USER or (`|`) PASS.

If you want add additional commands then simply tack them on to the end of the regex like...

```
/USER|PASS|PASV|.../
```

To my knowledge having an `OR` operator for content matches is not possible. Instead make two rules (which you indicated you don't want to do).

1. Looks for `USER`
2. Looks for `PASS`

I have seen many people indicate that using PCRE in Snort is expensive and should be avoided. Supposing it's used effectively I don't think there's a huge issue but have never captured performance metrics since I rarely have used PCRE for rule matching myself. If you do use the above PCRE rule than strongly consider beefing it up with `content` and `flow`.  How it's currently written Snort will inspect *every* packet that matches the header (`tcp any any -> any 21`)!

http://manual.snort.org/node32.html#SECTION004523000000000000000
http://manual.snort.org/node32.html#SECTION00451000000000000000
http://manual.snort.org/node33.html#SECTION00469000000000000000

Without more details of where you are/where you're trying to get to/what you have available you should also check out the FTP preprocessor to see if it can help achieve your overall goal.

http://manual.snort.org/node17.html#SECTION003210000000000000000